Best thing to do by private developers in case of impending death or plans to cease development on a personal private project
Suppose I have a personal private code project.
What should the developer do with the code in case of impending death or plans to cease development on their personal private project.
Suppose, they do not know what will happen to their account, or any of their accounts, after death.
For example, they don't know if they will be deleted.
So, even if they make their code public, they do not know if their account will be deleted.
Suppose, none of their children (if any), or family or social circle members, have, any interest (or knowledge, or inclination), to further development of or maintain, the code.
What should the developer do in these cases?
What, are, some available solutions out there (for this kind, of, situation)?
Thank you.

This is no different than with any other item in your posession. Take it off line and put it in your will if you guess the beneficiary will care about it. I would inquire first.

It's a bit different because the usual options aren't really available for digital assets. Sell it while you are alive and leave the money

Really this question could be about more general plans for lead developers exiting a project. Who owns the project? Who wants the project? How much is it worth to them? Do you sell it, hire new developers or decommission? maybe you can keep it running without maintenance? what about hand over documents etc etc

This is really two questions that are very related, but require different approaches.
Before Reading Further
If the developer has legal, financial, or contractual obligations or implications related to this code, then consult a lawyer. Do not continue reading this answer. Full stop. Go talk to a lawyer!
Assuming there are no legal, financial, or contractual implications, continue with the rest of this answer.
Impending Death
If you are the one whose death is pending, then I'm sorry to hear that. This must be so hard. Even if this is a loved one, it's still hard. I see a number of options:

Delete the code and account. This assumes that nobody is relying on this code.
Do nothing. Leave this up to other people. After death, the developer has nothing they can actively do.
Treat this as any other online account. Record username and password, which is given to a trusted person after the developer's death. Let that person deal with it.
Turn it public, and don't care.
Arrange for someone trusted to fork the repository and take responsibility. Then the developer can delete the code and disable their account.
Treat this as if the developer will continue living, but is no longer interested in developing the code (see next section). The developer is under no obligation to inform the public about this life changing event. It can be kept private. Nobody needs to know the difference between "this project is not supported because the developer died" versus "this project is not supported because the developer doesn't have time."

There could be others, but this is a balancing act between the person's time left alive (and feeling well enough to deal with this) and that person needing to tend to more important financial, legal, and family matters. Those take precedence.
Ceasing Development of Project
This one is a little easier to deal with.

Arrange for someone to take it over, then mark the repository as public/readonly or just let the person clone it once.
Make this thing public, and put a big note at the top of the README that says this is no longer maintained. Leave it up to the community to support it.

This could include downstream work in any package repositories to ensure new installs do not happen, and to provide information about who is maintaining it now.


If nobody is using this code anywhere, just don't care and delete it.


Really, if this is private and nobody else is using it, then do what you want. you have no legal or financial obligation to anyone, so you get to decide.

This may sound harsh, but nobody cares about your personal hobby project to automate the watering of your houseplants.
If you die, it'll go the way of most of your belongings: it will get removed and destroyed (just like most of your clothes, books, furniture will likely end up in a landfill or incinerator).
Either create a list of all your external accounts for your next of kin to have access to them, close and remove all those accounts yourself, or just don't bother and eventually the organisations the accounts are with are going to close and archive them because of inactivity.
Your github account in this is no different from your Warthunder account!
